# How can I arrange data.frame according to the factor levels?

Tags: r

there is data.frame df, i want to arrange (sort) it by index column according  the factor levels.
the result as "the wished data.frame". anyone can help ？ thanks!

```r
#create data frame

    df<-data.frame(index=c("b","a","e"),amount=c(10,76,60))
    df$index<-factor(df$index,levels=c("a","b","e"))

# current df
  index amount
1     b     10
2     a     76
3     e     60

# the wished data.frame
  index amount
1     a     76
2     b     10
3     e     60
```

Comment: df[sort(df$index),]

Comment: @DominikS.Meier That only works if the factor level order follows the natural sort order, which it might not.

Comment: you can define whatever order to you want with `ind <- ordered(df$index, levels = c("e", "b", "a"))` and then order with `df[ order(ind),]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

```
arrange(df, match(df$index, levels(df$index)))

  index amount
1     a     76
2     b     10
3     e     60
```

---

*Data*

```
df<-data.frame(index=c("b","a","e"),amount=c(10,76,60))
df$index<-factor(df$index,levels=c("b","e","a"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `order` :

```
df[order(df$index), ]

#  index amount
#2     a     76
#1     b     10
#3     e     60
```